# What is the "code" parameter at the end of outgoing links from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Whenever my app shares things with facebook through the opengraph objects/actions, the outgoing link that appears on facebook has a code= parameter with a very long hash. What is this? What does it do? Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

If your app has [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) turned on, the **code** query parameter should be the Auth Token used during the OAuth authentication process.

Your server should be able to basically send this AuthToken back to Facebook and get the Access Token associated with it...

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
   &code=THE_AUTH_TOKEN
```

You can read more about Facebook Server-Side Authentication. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)